# How to change the colour of row in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

[image]Hi

Can you please tell me how to change the colour of row in jquery mobile when user selects the row. The upper part of row is selectable. I need it become green when user selects the row. But, my problem is that I need select header (which is too be green not whole row) below field the same as white. I made a list view in a row, I have header(gray) and paragraph tag(white one). I need to change color of the gray field to green as well as the white to white when user selects a row.

here is fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/LxvyU/2/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    for(var i=0;i<name.length;i++){
        $('#folderData').append('<li class="rowclick" id="'+i+'"><h3>'+name[i]+'</h3><p>'+address[i]+'</p></li>');
    }

    // Refreshing the list
    $('#folderData').listview('refresh');
}); 
$(document).on('click','.rowclick',function(){
    alert(this.id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

## CSS

```
 .selected{
  background:green;
 }
```

## Javascript

```
$(document).on('click','.rowclick',function(){
  $('.ui-li-heading').removeClass('selected');
  $(this).find('.ui-li-heading').addClass('selected');    
});
```